# Which of the options is correct for assigning nC3 to an integer variable?

Tags: c

[image]

Why is the answer given option B? According to me, it should be D since it would clearly calculate the float value and then assign it to an integer variable.

Comment: Is it an exam question?

Comment: Here is your ans http://www.techtud.com/example/gate-2014-set-2-21-suppose-n-and-p-are-unsigned-int-variables

Comment: D does the multiplications as `unsigned int`, then converts to `double`, divides by 6.0, and converts back to `unsigned int`. That doesn't help much. If the multiplicands were converted to `double`, then your reasoning would be more or less OK. I'm not convinced about B either. It assumes that the compiler interprets the expression as `(((n * (n-1)) / 2) * (n - 2)) / 3`, and I'm not 100% sure that it is obliged to do that. If it does not evaluate left-to-right, then the result is not guaranteed. C is rejected assuming the L-R evaluation because `n*(n-1)` is not guaranteed to be divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations and integer overflow. If `n` is large, option B keeps the intermediate value the lowest. Option D gives a `double` which is not percise and still may overflow in the first part of the calculation.

Option C fails because the intermediate `n(n-1)/3` may not be an integer.